# Remote Desktop to Ubuntu 18.04 with Multiple DisplayPort Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, remote-desktop

I'm currently accessing a computer (Ubuntu 18.04) from my home using Teamviewer. At least one of the two monitors is connected to the remote PC via DisplayPort. When I remotely access the computer, only one monitor is visible and therefore I can't use the dual screen function in TeamViewer. This is affecting my productivity.

(I think that's because the PC sometimes treat DisplayPort monitors as unplugged after they are switched off?)

Are there any easy way to work around this?

1) If not then can you please recommend another remote desktop software? Please note that I'm not able to reach the remote computer using due to limitation of the firewall. Only web-based remote desktop software works
2) I use this remote computer during the day so adding a headless monitor plug probably isn't a good idea.